# How this code works for handling INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda, extension-methods, expression-trees

I see below code in this link : [An elegant way to implement INotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html)

I'm new to Expression Tree.can any one please explane how this code work simply?

thanks

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
   get { return _name; }
   set { PropertyChanged.ChangeAndNotify(ref _name, value, () => Name); }
}
```

---

```
public static bool ChangeAndNotify<T>(this PropertyChangedEventHandler handler,ref T field, T value, Expression<Func<T>> memberExpression)
    {
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("memberExpression");
        }
        var body = memberExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (body == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Lambda must return a property.");
        }
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var vmExpression = body.Expression as ConstantExpression;
        if (vmExpression != null)
        {
            LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(vmExpression);
            Delegate vmFunc = lambda.Compile();
            object sender = vmFunc.DynamicInvoke();

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(body.Member.Name));
            }
        }

        field = value;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression tree is an object-oriented *representation* of an expression at runtime. The C# compiler can automatically write ***a limited subset*** of expressions as `Expression<>` instances, via a lambda - i.e.

```
Func<string> anonMethod = () => "abc"; // this is a delegate
Expression<Func<string>> expression = () => "abc"; // this is an expression
```

The above will have a `ConstantExpression`; your example will have a `ConstantExpression` that captures `this` and a `MemberExpression` that wraps that constant (`this`) and the member (`.Name`). Then at runtime, it locates the `MemberExpression`, which has a `MemberInfo`, which has a `Name`. It could even have a `ConstantExpression` to a *capture class*, a `MemberExpression` to `this` (as a field on the capture-class), and *then* a `MemberExpression` to `.Name`.

The difference is subtle, but an expression can be pulled apart and inspected at runtime - which is critical for LINQ. However: while the compiler can *write* these, they are not free to inspect; they have cost too.

IMO, perhaps stick with:

```
public string Name
{
   get { return _name; }
   set { SomeSimpleNotifyMethod(ref _name, value, this, "Name"; }
}
```

this is simpler and faster (obviously, changing the method to take a string that it passes to the event).

Comment: Thanks.you are a great developer.I don't understand `this`.`this` in this example point to `PropertyChangedEventHandler` and how lamda expression wrap `this` and `Name` together?is `MemberExpression` is delegate(lambda) part of Expression Tree?why in line 7 got body of Expression and again in line 17 get Expressoin of body?sorry but it's to comlecated for me.

Comment: @Nima no, the delegate is not part of the lambda; that was for contrast only. The bit on line 7 is identifying that the expression is actually a member-access; the bit on line 17 is looking for the object (`this` in my discussion above); rather than understand the entire tree they've chosen to do a `Compile()`/`DynamicInvoke()`, which is, btw, very slow (relatively speaking). Again, I don't recommend that code.

Comment: you say : The above will have a `ConstantExpression`.if so why in line 17 convert body to `ConstantExpression`?

Comment: @Nima it doesn't; the `MemberExpression` is, like in C#, a combination of *an object* and *a member*, i.e. in C# `this.Name`; here, the *target object* is specified **as an `Expression`** (just like in C# really, i.e. `{some compound expression}.Name`). It is testing *that* to see if it is constant.

Comment: Thanks can you please recommend a reference for professional c# programming specialy for Expression Tree,Lamda Expression,delegate and reflection.

Comment: @Nima no, not really. It is a bit of a niche; I've blogged about it a bit, etc, but nothing major. To be honest, if you play with it a little while it makes a lot more sense ;p It is wicked confusing initially - don't worry, that is normal. You aren't going mad - this stuff is crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension method that is able to determine sender and property name just by inspecting lambda expression tree and without any major performance impact:

```
public static class PropertyChangedExtensions
{
    public static void Raise(this PropertyChangedEventHandler handler, Expression<Func<object>> property)
    {
        if (handler == null)
            return;

        var boxingExpr = property.Body as UnaryExpression;

        var memberExpr = (MemberExpression)(boxingExpr == null ? 
            property.Body : boxingExpr.Operand);

        var propertyName = memberExpr.Member.Name;
        var sender = ((ConstantExpression)memberExpr.Expression).Value;
        handler.Invoke(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and usage is the same as you have right now:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set
    {
        name = value;
        PropertyChanged.Raise(() => Name);
    }
}
```